# php arrays one array from two

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two arrays:

```
$ids:

    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 8
)

$ranks:

Array
(
    [0] => Rank1
    [1] => Rank2
    [2] => Rank3
    [3] => Rank5
    [4] => NoName
)
```

How can I create an array from these two, like this `array('1'=>'Rank1','2'=>'Rank2','3'=>'Rank3','4'=>'Rank5','8'=>'Noname')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function, which allows you to map an array of keys to an array of values in one associative array.

```
$ids_ranks = array_combine($ids, $ranks);
print_r($ids_ranks);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Rank1
    [2] => Rank2
    [3] => Rank3
    [4] => Rank5
    [8] => NoName
)
```